# Lunch and Make fails in building AOSP (Android N) for Nexus 6p

Tags: android, android-source, nexus-6p

Here is my build environment:
I build android N on my mac using case-sensitive image. On the same image, I can successfully android 5.0.1 for nexus5. Now I want to do that for nexus 6p using android 7.0.0_r6. Repo sync is successful.

There are multiple errors:

1

```
Unknown option: -C
usage: git [--version] [--help] [-c name=value]
           [--exec-path[=<path>]] [--html-path] [--man-path] [--info-path]
           [-p|--paginate|--no-pager] [--no-replace-objects] [--bare]
           [--git-dir=<path>] [--work-tree=<path>] [--namespace=<name>]
           <command> [<args>]
```

2

```
localhost:n_android guest$ make -j12
date: 1475895550: No such file or directory
date: 1475895550: No such file or directory
```

3

```
build/kati/eval.h:18:10: fatal error: 'unordered_map' file not found
```

From the full log below, the first issue is in "lunch" command.
Has anybody seen this kind of error? Any comment is welcome! Thanks!

```
localhost:n_android guest$ source build/envsetup.sh 
including device/asus/fugu/vendorsetup.sh
including device/generic/mini-emulator-arm64/vendorsetup.sh
including device/generic/mini-emulator-armv7-a-neon/vendorsetup.sh
including device/generic/mini-emulator-mips/vendorsetup.sh
including device/generic/mini-emulator-mips64/vendorsetup.sh
including device/generic/mini-emulator-x86/vendorsetup.sh
including device/generic/mini-emulator-x86_64/vendorsetup.sh
including device/google/dragon/vendorsetup.sh
including device/htc/flounder/vendorsetup.sh
including device/huawei/angler/vendorsetup.sh
including device/lge/bullhead/vendorsetup.sh
including device/linaro/hikey/vendorsetup.sh
including device/moto/shamu/vendorsetup.sh
including sdk/bash_completion/adb.bash
localhost:n_android guest$ lunch aosp_angler-userdebug 
date: 1475895540: No such file or directory
date: 1475895540: No such file or directory

============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=7.0
TARGET_PRODUCT=aosp_angler
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=userdebug
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm64
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv8-a
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=cortex-a53
TARGET_2ND_ARCH=arm
TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a-neon
TARGET_2ND_CPU_VARIANT=cortex-a53.a57
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=darwin
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Darwin-15.3.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
HOST_CROSS_OS=
HOST_CROSS_ARCH=
HOST_CROSS_2ND_ARCH=
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=NRD90U
OUT_DIR=out
============================================
localhost:n_android guest$ make -j12
date: 1475895550: No such file or directory
date: 1475895550: No such file or directory
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=7.0
TARGET_PRODUCT=aosp_angler
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=userdebug
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm64
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv8-a
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=cortex-a53
TARGET_2ND_ARCH=arm
TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a-neon
TARGET_2ND_CPU_VARIANT=cortex-a53.a57
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=darwin
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Darwin-15.3.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
HOST_CROSS_OS=
HOST_CROSS_ARCH=
HOST_CROSS_2ND_ARCH=
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=NRD90U
OUT_DIR=out
============================================
Unknown option: -C
usage: git [--version] [--help] [-c name=value]
           [--exec-path[=<path>]] [--html-path] [--man-path] [--info-path]
           [-p|--paginate|--no-pager] [--no-replace-objects] [--bare]
           [--git-dir=<path>] [--work-tree=<path>] [--namespace=<name>]
           <command> [<args>]
prebuilts/clang/host/darwin-x86/clang-2690385/bin/clang++   -fno-exceptions -Wno-multichar -m64 -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -isysroot /Applications/Xcode-5.0.2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -DMACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.8 -fPIC -funwind-tables -DANDROID -fmessage-length=0 -W -Wall -Wno-unused -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -O2 -g -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -UDEBUG  -D__compiler_offsetof=__builtin_offsetof -Werror=int-conversion -Wno-reserved-id-macro -Wno-format-pedantic -Wno-unused-command-line-argument   -integrated-as -fstack-protector-strong    -integrated-as -target x86_64-apple-darwin   -isystem /Applications/Xcode-5.0.2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1 -Wsign-promo  -Wno-inconsistent-missing-override    -target x86_64-apple-darwin -c -std=c++11 -g -W -Wall -MMD -MP -O -DNOLOG -march=native -o out/host/darwin-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/ckati_intermediates/dep.o build/kati/dep.cc
prebuilts/clang/host/darwin-x86/clang-2690385/bin/clang++   -fno-exceptions -Wno-multichar -m64 -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -isysroot /Applications/Xcode-5.0.2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -DMACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.8 -fPIC -funwind-tables -DANDROID -fmessage-length=0 -W -Wall -Wno-unused -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -O2 -g -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -UDEBUG  -D__compiler_offsetof=__builtin_offsetof -Werror=int-conversion -Wno-reserved-id-macro -Wno-format-pedantic -Wno-unused-command-line-argument   -integrated-as -fstack-protector-strong    -integrated-as -target x86_64-apple-darwin   -isystem /Applications/Xcode-5.0.2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1 -Wsign-promo  -Wno-inconsistent-missing-override    -target x86_64-apple-darwin -c -std=c++11 -g -W -Wall -MMD -MP -O -DNOLOG -march=native -o out/host/darwin-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/ckati_intermediates/eval.o build/kati/eval.cc
prebuilts/clang/host/darwin-x86/clang-2690385/bin/clang++   -fno-exceptions -Wno-multichar -m64 -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -isysroot /Applications/Xcode-5.0.2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -DMACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.8 -fPIC -funwind-tables -DANDROID -fmessage-length=0 -W -Wall -Wno-unused -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -O2 -g -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -UDEBUG  -D__compiler_offsetof=__builtin_offsetof -Werror=int-conversion -Wno-reserved-id-macro -Wno-format-pedantic -Wno-unused-command-line-argument   -integrated-as -fstack-protector-strong    -integrated-as -target x86_64-apple-darwin   -isystem /Applications/Xcode-5.0.2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1 -Wsign-promo  -Wno-inconsistent-missing-override    -target x86_64-apple-darwin -c -std=c++11 -g -W -Wall -MMD -MP -O -DNOLOG -march=native -o out/host/darwin-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/ckati_intermediates/exec.o build/kati/exec.cc
prebuilts/clang/host/darwin-x86/clang-2690385/bin/clang++   -fno-exceptions -Wno-multichar -m64 -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -isysroot /Applications/Xcode-5.0.2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -DMACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.8 -fPIC -funwind-tables -DANDROID -fmessage-length=0 -W -Wall -Wno-unused -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -O2 -g -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -UDEBUG  -D__compiler_offsetof=__builtin_offsetof -Werror=int-conversion -Wno-reserved-id-macro -Wno-format-pedantic -Wno-unused-command-line-argument   -integrated-as -fstack-protector-strong    -integrated-as -target x86_64-apple-darwin   -isystem /Applications/Xcode-5.0.2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1 -Wsign-promo  -Wno-inconsistent-missing-override    -target x86_64-apple-darwin -c -std=c++11 -g -W -Wall -MMD -MP -O -DNOLOG -march=native -o out/host/darwin-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/ckati_intermediates/file.o build/kati/file.cc
prebuilts/clang/host/darwin-x86/clang-2690385/bin/clang++   -fno-exceptions -Wno-multichar -m64 -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -isysroot /Applications/Xcode-5.0.2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -DMACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.8 -fPIC -funwind-tables -DANDROID -fmessage-length=0 -W -Wall -Wno-unused -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -O2 -g -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -UDEBUG  -D__compiler_offsetof=__builtin_offsetof -Werror=int-conversion -Wno-reserved-id-macro -Wno-format-pedantic -Wno-unused-command-line-argument   -integrated-as -fstack-protector-strong    -integrated-as -target x86_64-apple-darwin   -isystem /Applications/Xcode-5.0.2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1 -Wsign-promo  -Wno-inconsistent-missing-override    -target x86_64-apple-darwin -c -std=c++11 -g -W -Wall -MMD -MP -O -DNOLOG -march=native -o out/host/darwin-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/ckati_intermediates/file_cache.o build/kati/file_cache.cc
prebuilts/clang/host/darwin-x86/clang-2690385/bin/clang++   -fno-exceptions -Wno-multichar -m64 -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -isysroot /Applications/Xcode-5.0.2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -DMACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.8 -fPIC -funwind-tables -DANDROID -fmessage-length=0 -W -Wall -Wno-unused -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -O2 -g -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -UDEBUG  -D__compiler_offsetof=__builtin_offsetof -Werror=int-conversion -Wno-reserved-id-macro -Wno-format-pedantic -Wno-unused-command-line-argument   -integrated-as -fstack-protector-strong    -integrated-as -target x86_64-apple-darwin   -isystem /Applications/Xcode-5.0.2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1 -Wsign-promo  -Wno-inconsistent-missing-override    -target x86_64-apple-darwin -c -std=c++11 -g -W -Wall -MMD -MP -O -DNOLOG -march=native -o out/host/darwin-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/ckati_intermediates/expr.o build/kati/expr.cc
prebuilts/clang/host/darwin-x86/clang-2690385/bin/clang++   -fno-exceptions -Wno-multichar -m64 -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -isysroot /Applications/Xcode-5.0.2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -DMACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.8 -fPIC -funwind-tables -DANDROID -fmessage-length=0 -W -Wall -Wno-unused -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -O2 -g -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -UDEBUG  -D__compiler_offsetof=__builtin_offsetof -Werror=int-conversion -Wno-reserved-id-macro -Wno-format-pedantic -Wno-unused-command-line-argument   -integrated-as -fstack-protector-strong    -integrated-as -target x86_64-apple-darwin   -isystem /Applications/Xcode-5.0.2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1 -Wsign-promo  -Wno-inconsistent-missing-override    -target x86_64-apple-darwin -c -std=c++11 -g -W -Wall -MMD -MP -O -DNOLOG -march=native -o out/host/darwin-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/ckati_intermediates/command.o build/kati/command.cc
prebuilts/clang/host/darwin-x86/clang-2690385/bin/clang++   -fno-exceptions -Wno-multichar -m64 -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -isysroot /Applications/Xcode-5.0.2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -DMACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.8 -fPIC -funwind-tables -DANDROID -fmessage-length=0 -W -Wall -Wno-unused -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -O2 -g -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -UDEBUG  -D__compiler_offsetof=__builtin_offsetof -Werror=int-conversion -Wno-reserved-id-macro -Wno-format-pedantic -Wno-unused-command-line-argument   -integrated-as -fstack-protector-strong    -integrated-as -target x86_64-apple-darwin   -isystem /Applications/Xcode-5.0.2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1 -Wsign-promo  -Wno-inconsistent-missing-override    -target x86_64-apple-darwin -c -std=c++11 -g -W -Wall -MMD -MP -O -DNOLOG -march=native -o out/host/darwin-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/ckati_intermediates/find.o build/kati/find.cc
prebuilts/clang/host/darwin-x86/clang-2690385/bin/clang++   -fno-exceptions -Wno-multichar -m64 -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -isysroot /Applications/Xcode-5.0.2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -DMACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.8 -fPIC -funwind-tables -DANDROID -fmessage-length=0 -W -Wall -Wno-unused -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -O2 -g -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -UDEBUG  -D__compiler_offsetof=__builtin_offsetof -Werror=int-conversion -Wno-reserved-id-macro -Wno-format-pedantic -Wno-unused-command-line-argument   -integrated-as -fstack-protector-strong    -integrated-as -target x86_64-apple-darwin   -isystem /Applications/Xcode-5.0.2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1 -Wsign-promo  -Wno-inconsistent-missing-override    -target x86_64-apple-darwin -c -std=c++11 -g -W -Wall -MMD -MP -O -DNOLOG -march=native -o out/host/darwin-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/ckati_intermediates/fileutil.o build/kati/fileutil.cc
prebuilts/clang/host/darwin-x86/clang-2690385/bin/clang++   -fno-exceptions -Wno-multichar -m64 -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -isysroot /Applications/Xcode-5.0.2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -DMACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.8 -fPIC -funwind-tables -DANDROID -fmessage-length=0 -W -Wall -Wno-unused -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -O2 -g -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -UDEBUG  -D__compiler_offsetof=__builtin_offsetof -Werror=int-conversion -Wno-reserved-id-macro -Wno-format-pedantic -Wno-unused-command-line-argument   -integrated-as -fstack-protector-strong    -integrated-as -target x86_64-apple-darwin   -isystem /Applications/Xcode-5.0.2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1 -Wsign-promo  -Wno-inconsistent-missing-override    -target x86_64-apple-darwin -c -std=c++11 -g -W -Wall -MMD -MP -O -DNOLOG -march=native -o out/host/darwin-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/ckati_intermediates/affinity.o build/kati/affinity.cc
prebuilts/clang/host/darwin-x86/clang-2690385/bin/clang++   -fno-exceptions -Wno-multichar -m64 -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -isysroot /Applications/Xcode-5.0.2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -DMACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.8 -fPIC -funwind-tables -DANDROID -fmessage-length=0 -W -Wall -Wno-unused -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -O2 -g -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -UDEBUG  -D__compiler_offsetof=__builtin_offsetof -Werror=int-conversion -Wno-reserved-id-macro -Wno-format-pedantic -Wno-unused-command-line-argument   -integrated-as -fstack-protector-strong    -integrated-as -target x86_64-apple-darwin   -isystem /Applications/Xcode-5.0.2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1 -Wsign-promo  -Wno-inconsistent-missing-override    -target x86_64-apple-darwin -c -std=c++11 -g -W -Wall -MMD -MP -O -DNOLOG -march=native -o out/host/darwin-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/ckati_intermediates/flags.o build/kati/flags.cc
prebuilts/clang/host/darwin-x86/clang-2690385/bin/clang++   -fno-exceptions -Wno-multichar -m64 -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -isysroot /Applications/Xcode-5.0.2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -DMACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.8 -fPIC -funwind-tables -DANDROID -fmessage-length=0 -W -Wall -Wno-unused -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -O2 -g -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -UDEBUG  -D__compiler_offsetof=__builtin_offsetof -Werror=int-conversion -Wno-reserved-id-macro -Wno-format-pedantic -Wno-unused-command-line-argument   -integrated-as -fstack-protector-strong    -integrated-as -target x86_64-apple-darwin   -isystem /Applications/Xcode-5.0.2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1 -Wsign-promo  -Wno-inconsistent-missing-override    -target x86_64-apple-darwin -c -std=c++11 -g -W -Wall -MMD -MP -O -DNOLOG -march=native -o out/host/darwin-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/ckati_intermediates/func.o build/kati/func.cc
In file included from build/kati/eval.cc:17:
build/kati/eval.h:18:10: fatal error: 'unordered_map' file not found
#include <unordered_map>
         ^
build/kati/exec.cc:23:10: fatal error: 'unordered_map' file not found
#include <unordered_map>
         ^
In file included from build/kati/fileutil.cc:17:
build/kati/fileutil.h:20:10: fatal error: 'unordered_map' file not found
#include <unordered_map>
         ^
In file included from build/kati/file_cache.cc:17:
build/kati/file_cache.h:20:10: fatal error: 'unordered_set' file not found
#include <unordered_set>
         ^
In file included from build/kati/dep.cc:17:
build/kati/dep.h:19:10: fatal error: 'unordered_map' file not found
#include <unordered_map>
         ^
In file included from build/kati/find.cc:17:
build/kati/find.h:20:10: fatal error: 'unordered_set' file not found
#include <unordered_set>
         ^
1 error generated.
In file included from build/kati/expr.cc:17:
In file included from build/kati/expr.h:21:
build/kati/string_piece.h:213:19: error: explicit specialization of non-template struct 'hash'
template<> struct hash<StringPiece> {
                  ^   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make: *** [out/host/darwin-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/ckati_intermediates/file_cache.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
In file included from build/kati/expr.cc:21:
build/kati/eval.h:18:10: fatal error: 'unordered_map' file not found
#include <unordered_map>
         ^
In file included from build/kati/affinity.cc:17:
In file included from build/kati/flags.h:21:
build/kati/string_piece.h:213:19: error: explicit specialization of non-template struct 'hash'
template<> struct hash<StringPiece> {
                  ^   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from build/kati/flags.cc:17:
In file included from build/kati/flags.h:21:
build/kati/string_piece.h:213:19: error: explicit specialization of non-template struct 'hash'
template<> struct hash<StringPiece> {
                  ^   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from build/kati/affinity.cc:17:
In file included from build/kati/flags.h:22:
build/kati/symtab.h:88:19: error: explicit specialization of non-template struct 'hash'
template<> struct hash<Symbol> {
                  ^   ~~~~~~~~
In file included from build/kati/command.cc:17:
In file included from build/kati/command.h:20:
In file included from build/kati/symtab.h:21:
build/kati/string_piece.h:213:19: error: explicit specialization of non-template struct 'hash'
template<> struct hash<StringPiece> {In file included from 
build/kati/flags.cc:                  ^   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~17
:
In file included from build/kati/flags.h:22:
build/kati/symtab.h:88:19: error: explicit specialization of non-template struct 'hash'
template<> struct hash<Symbol> {
                  ^   ~~~~~~~~
build/kati/symtab.h:88:19: error: redefinition of 'hash'
build/kati/string_piece.h:213:19: note: previous definition is here
template<> struct hash<StringPiece> {
                  ^
build/kati/symtab.h:88:19: error: redefinition of 'hash'
build/kati/string_piece.h:213:19: note: previous definition is here
template<> struct hash<StringPiece> {
                  ^
In file included from build/kati/file.cc:24:
In file included from build/kati/log.h:23:
In file included from build/kati/flags.h:21:
build/kati/string_piece.h:213:19: error: explicit specialization of non-template struct 'hash'
template<> struct hash<StringPiece> {
                  ^   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from build/kati/command.cc:17:
In file included from build/kati/command.h:20:
build/kati/symtab.h:88:19: error: explicit specialization of non-template struct 'hash'
template<> struct hash<Symbol> {
                  ^   ~~~~~~~~
build/kati/symtab.h:88:19: error: redefinition of 'hash'
build/kati/string_piece.h:213:19: note: previous definition is here
template<> struct hash<StringPiece> {
                  ^
In file included from build/kati/file.cc:24:
In file included from build/kati/log.h:23:
In file included from build/kati/flags.h:22:
build/kati/symtab.h:88:19: error: explicit specialization of non-template struct 'hash'
template<> struct hash<Symbol> {
                  ^   ~~~~~~~~
build/kati/symtab.h:88:19: error: redefinition of 'hash'
build/kati/string_piece.h:213:19: note: previous definition is here
template<> struct hash<StringPiece> {
                  ^
build/kati/command.cc:19:10: fatal error: 'unordered_map' file not found
#include <unordered_map>
         ^
3 errors generated.
1 error generated.
In file included from build/kati/func.cc:17:
In file included from build/kati/func.h:22:
In file included from build/kati/expr.h:21:
build/kati/string_piece.h:213:19: error: explicit specialization of non-template struct 'hash'
template<> struct hash<StringPiece> {
                  ^   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make: *** [out/host/darwin-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/ckati_intermediates/affinity.o] Error 1
make: *** [out/host/darwin-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/ckati_intermediates/eval.o] Error 1
In file included from build/kati/func.cc:17:
build/kati/func.h:46:3: error: unknown type name 'unique_ptr'
  unique_ptr<FindCommand> find;
  ^
build/kati/func.h:46:13: error: expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers
  unique_ptr<FindCommand> find;
  ~~~~~~~~~~^
1 error generated.
make: *** [out/host/darwin-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/ckati_intermediates/exec.o] Error 1
3 errors generated.
3 errors generated.
make: *** [out/host/darwin-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/ckati_intermediates/flags.o] Error 1
make: *** [out/host/darwin-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/ckati_intermediates/file.o] Error 1
4 errors generated.
2 errors generated.
make: *** [out/host/darwin-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/ckati_intermediates/command.o] Error 1
make: *** [out/host/darwin-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/ckati_intermediates/expr.o] Error 1
1 error generated.
1 error generated.
make: *** [out/host/darwin-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/ckati_intermediates/fileutil.o] Error 1
make: *** [out/host/darwin-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/ckati_intermediates/find.o] Error 1
build/kati/func.cc:28:10: fatal error: 'unordered_map' file not found
#include <unordered_map>
         ^
4 errors generated.
make: *** [out/host/darwin-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/ckati_intermediates/func.o] Error 1
1 error generated.
make: *** [out/host/darwin-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/ckati_intermediates/dep.o] Error 1

#### make failed to build some targets (1 seconds) ####

localhost:n_android guest$
```

Comment: I realised I need to update my Xcode and port and Git... whatever.  One thing proves my thought, in latest git (2.10.1), I found there is a "-C" option, but in current git (1.8.3.4), "-C" is not supported. So my guessing may help...

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found way for it.

1. Update your Xcode, port to latest you can find. 
   Below command, you may also need it.

`sudo port install gmake libsdl gnupg git`

2. Check if you have install multiple Xcode. If so, use /usr/bin/xcode-select to choose latest one. For example, Xcode 8.0.
3. You will find there is not 10.11 in Xcode 8.0. You can download it from [xcode SDKs repo](https://github.com/phracker/MacOSX-SDKs/releases). Put it to /Applications/XCode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk.

Then, you will find the world is better. Enjoy.